# Django adding `choices` to an inherited model field

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, overriding, multi-table-inheritance

Using multi-table inheritance, I have two models:

```python
class Bird(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField()

class Bluebird(Bird):
    ...
```

Using these models, I can do this:

```python
birds = Bird.objects.all()
for bird in birds:
    print bird.color
```

This is super simple, but I don't like allowing people to define arbitrary color values in some cases. For example, I want to prevent users from creating `Bluebird` objects for which the color field is set to anything but `"blue"` or, in more rare cases, `"grey"` or `"brown"`. In other words, I want to set the `choices` kwarg on the inherited `color` field from within the `Bluebird` model. From a cursory internet search, it seems that Django doesn't currently allow model subclasses to override the fields from a parent.

How does one retain access to the `color` field in the parent class while defining acceptable choices in the child?

EDIT: This question focuses on Django < 1.8. In 1.8, the ability to pass a callable for a field's `choices` kwarg was added, and while that would be nice, I'm dealing with a system that hasn't yet been upgraded and upgrading is not currently an option.

Comment: A simple approach might be to leave `color` alone and just do it via validation. (That is, the user can choose something other than `blue`, but the validation will reject it as an invalid choice.)

Comment: While that would keep the data valid, the user experience would suffer as a result. In the worst-case scenario (i.e., they haven't the foggiest idea what colors a certain kind of bird can be), they would be reduced to guessing unless the valid options are presented to them by the form. Presenting options by overriding the ModelForm field is currently how I'm approaching this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use a property.

You can define the color value for each model and then return that as a property, if the color will be fixed, you don't need it in the database.

```
class Bird(models.Model):
   COLOR = None

   @property
   def color(self):
       return self.COLOR

class BlueBird(Bird):
   COLOR = 'Blue'

>>> b = BlueBird()
>>> b.color
'Blue'
```

Comment: This probably won't help b/c the color should be stored in the database.